# Spring Security Requests are 403

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-rest

I am currently working on an application with spring, and I currently face the problem that all requests I do return the error 403 - Forbidden. It is not only [post,put,patch,delete], but also get. Also, I have csrf already disabled.
Here my SecurityConfig:

```java
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .anonymous().and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/signin").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/signup").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/rss/feed").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/article/{guid}").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint).and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .csrf().disable().cors();

    }
```

And here one of the endpoints which is not working properly:

```java
    @PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ADMIN', 'PUBLISHER', 'USER')")
    @GetMapping("/users/current")
    public User getCurrent(@RequestHeader Map<String, String> headers){
        String token = headers.get("Authorization");
        System.out.println("Current user request");
        return userAuthService.getUserByUsername(jwtUtil.getUser(token).getUsername());
    }
```

And yes, I know that `csrf().disable()` is dangerous, I disabled it for now to see if it is some problem with csrf.

Here my JwtAuthenticationFilter:

```java
@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtUtil jwtUtil;
    @Autowired
    private UserAuthService userAuthService;
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String header = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if(header == null){
            throw new NullPointerException("No headers");
        }
        if (!header.startsWith("Bearer")) {
            throw new JwtTokenMissingException("No JWT token found in the request headers");
        }
        String token = header.substring(7);
        // Optional - verification
        jwtUtil.validateToken(token);
        UserVo userVo = jwtUtil.getUser(token);
        UserDetails userDetails = userAuthService.loadUserByUsername(userVo.getUsername());

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
        usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
        if (SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Edit: I enabled Security logging and got the following error on Spring console:

```
2022-04-04 18:22:26.611 DEBUG 9804 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.a.i.a.MethodSecurityInterceptor    : Failed to authorize ReflectiveMethodInvocation: public at.brigot.kainblog.pojos.User at.brigot.kainblog.controller.AuthController.getCurrent(java.util.Map); target is of class [at.brigot.kainblog.controller.AuthController] with attributes [[authorize: 'hasAnyRole('ADMIN', 'PUBLISHER', 'USER')', filter: 'null', filterTarget: 'null']]
```

Also if needed, here the full request info I got from spring:

```
************************************************************
Request received for GET '/users/current':

org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@1d49a6ca

servletPath:/users/current
pathInfo:null
headers: 
host: localhost:8080
connection: keep-alive
sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="98", "Opera GX";v="84"
accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJnb3RwZWQxNyIsInJvbGVzIjpbIkFETUlOIiwiVVNFUiJdLCJpYXQiOjE2NDkwODkyMDcsImV4cCI6MTY0OTA4OTM4N30.b5vg-azO433Ozk8GoiakQC-T2ULdFVsde6MrJhW8XpIhA5k5AtA_Q6i0vuCGATQV8RwteMzBc86CzKmuQ7kuYA
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.109 Safari/537.36 OPR/84.0.4316.52
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
origin: http://localhost:3000
sec-fetch-site: same-site
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-dest: empty
referer: http://localhost:3000/
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7


Security filter chain: [
  WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
  SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
  HeaderWriterFilter
  CorsFilter
  LogoutFilter
  JwtAuthenticationFilter
  RequestCacheAwareFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
  SessionManagementFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  FilterSecurityInterceptor
]


************************************************************
```

Comment: You are securing your endpoint and you are getting forbidden. If you send jwt token in requests most probably you have a problem with filter

Comment: If you are throwing exception in filter, and does not catch it how can you send valid response to user? It is not controller so controller advice can not catch it

Comment: The application never enters the AuthenticationEntryPoint during the get request on the endpoint in the code above. My Signin endpoint works fine and I get a valid token back and if I don't use that token, I get a 401 - Unauthorized(which should be the case). Also, my spring application is not throwing  any exceptions to console, and the 403 - forbidden error page also does not contain any further information.

Comment: @gotped17 What is the value of `userDetails.getAuthorities()`?